# Plotly Treemap - Creating Treemap using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['flag', 'flag', 'sweets'], 'need_1': [['US'], ['Finland'], ['chocolate'], 'need_2': [['US', ['Britain'], ['licorice'], 'number': [2, 4, 5})

<OUT>
  Type    need_1       need_2        number     
   flag   US           US            2
   flag   Finland      Britain       4
   sweet  chocolate    licorice      5
```

I wish to create a treemap using `Plotly`.

So far I have this:

```
fig = px.treemap(eet_2022_drop, 
    path = ['type','need_1', 'need_2''], 
    values = 'number',
    width = 800,
    height = 600)
fig.show()
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Non-leaves rows are not permitted in the dataframe
```

Any ideas what the error is alluding to and how may I be able to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Please, give a try to solve it by this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63891033/16733101

Comment: eet_2022_drop dataframe may contain Nan values.